# PHP tls handshake with ios using certificate pinning

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, ssl, ssl-certificate

My question relates to creating a secure network connection between a iOS mobile App and a Web server scripted in PHP with a tls certificate issued by a CA .

I understand the theory behind the process of creating the https connection but the actual implementation on server side (php code/server configuration)is where i have become confused -  how does the server initiate a certificate handshake (authentication challenge) back to a NSUrlSession request in objective c with the intention of using certificate pinning on the iOS side?

note - The certificate is not self signed

Comment: Certificate pinning is a client only thing, i.e. the client expects only a specific certificate or public key. The server side just works as usual, i.e. serving the certificate the client expects. And this is also unrelated to PHP since the TLS connection will be done by the web server and not by the PHP script.

Comment: i think i understand - so say the client makes normal https request to the server (the server requires NO php code to reply) and sends back the public key. At this point the client uses a pinned certificate (that it stored previous to its orignal request) to compare against the public key that is received from the server? if the keys are the same the connection process continues

Comment: Certificate pinning in an application means that the expected public key is build into the application so that the application knows what to expect on first contact already. What you describe is called TOFU (Trust On First Use) and is used in browsers with the [HPKP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Public_Key_Pinning) header: I would recommend you study [OWASP: Public Key Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning).

Comment: so your telling me that no PHP code is required to initiate an authentication challenge to an ios client?

Comment: exactly. TLS is done by the web server and PHP is only involved after the TLS handshake is done.